# Can this integral be written in terms of special functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, special-functions

I'm trying to find some nice expression for integrals of the form
$$
I(a,b,c)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{1}{({a x^4+ b x^2+c})^{3/2}}.
$$

So far I failed to find a rewriting of this in terms of special function (elliptic, hypergeometric, Bessel..) but something tells me that this should be possible. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: This is an elliptic integral.  Maple writes it in terms of elliptic integrals $E$ and $F$.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise? Maybe write it down? Trying to evaluate with mathematica doesn't give me an eplicit answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the denominator has a real zero, the integral diverges.  So assume
the denominator has no real zeros.  Factor it.  For example,
we get this if $u,v>0$, $u \ne v$:
$$
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\! \frac{{\rm d}x}{\left(  \left( {x}^{2}+u \right)  \left( {
x}^{2}+v \right)  \right) ^{3/2}}\,
={\frac {2}{\sqrt {v}\;
 \left( u-v \right) ^{2}\;u} \left[  \left( u+v \right) {\rm E}
 \left( \sqrt {1-{\frac {u}{v}}} \;\right) -2u\;{\rm K} \left( 
\sqrt {1-{\frac {u}{v}}} \;\right)  \right] }
$$
and in case $u=v$ we get $(3/8)\pi u^{-5/2}$.
The complete elliptic integrals E and K may be found [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)